# start another bash script from main bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script, from which I need to start another script with `source`. This is working fine, but I also need to pass the 2nd script parameters.

Example:

```
source /usr/local/scripts/parallel.sh test --gnu
```

So I need to start `parallel.sh` with a given data-source file called `test`, and I also need to assign a parameter `--gnu` at the end. But it is not recognizing the file and the parameter.

Comment: Why do you need to source it? Can't you just call it normally?

Comment: you mean with ./path/to/script?

Comment: Yes. Sourcing is used when you want to import variables of functions from the script.

Comment: Sourcing will mean that it runs in the same process space so any variables will be visible and potentially mutable. Also if your process crashes it'll crash the whole thing, not just `parallel.sh` Running it, on the other hand, will put it into a separate process, variable will only be seen in `parallel.sh` if you've exported them and any env var you change will be lost once control returns to your calling script.

Comment: Are your `test --gnu` parameters being passed to `parallel.sh`? If so, that should work fine. You should be able to reference them as `${1}` and `${2}` within `parallel.sh`

Comment: now i am getting `./usr/local/scripts/parallel.sh: No such file or directory`

i am calling the script with `./usr/local/scripts/parallel.sh test --gnu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`source` command](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) is likely not what you're looking for.

> When a script is run using source it runs within the existing shell, any variables created or modified by the script will remain available after the script completes. In contrast if the script is run just as filename, then a separate subshell (with a completely separate set of variables) would be spawned to run the script.

So, unless you need access to variables or functions inside `parallel.sh`, just call it directly:

```
/usr/local/scripts/parallel.sh test --gnu
```

As long as the script is executable (`chmod +x /usr/local/scripts/parallel.sh`) and set up to work with the options you're passing (`$1` will contain "test" and `$2` will contain "--gnu") it should work just fine.